# Query String opening page

Tags: web-part, query-string

I have web part with link buttons.

How do I open a new page when I click on a link button and also use a query string for sending my variable id?

Answer (score 1):

Will this work for you?

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="lbJan" OnClick="lbMonth_Click" Text="ClickMe' CommandArgument="1" >


protected void lbMonth_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  string redirect = "<script>window.open('/Pages/Page1.aspx?sID=" + e.CommandArgument.ToString() + "' );</script>"; 
  Response.Write(redirect);
}
```

Comment: Great wimdp. Please mark as answer so other users know